# How can I get iPad quicktype to use an Italian word list

Tags: ipad

I'm learning Italian, and have good dictionaries downloaded.  Looking up English words is a breeze, and I'd like to do the same for Italian words.

But I can't find how to do it.

Comment: Do you have the Italian dictionaries provided by Apple downloaded and checked in settings > general > dictionary?  If so, does that not do what you want?  Please explain.

Comment: I have the dictionaries, but I'm looking for a word list for slide-to-type, 'swype', to use.

The word 'gone' is found, but not the word 'andato'.  Just the simple word list - it must exist, Italians use iPad quicktype...

Comment: If it doesn't do what you want when the Italian keyboard is active, there's no way to add things like this in iOS as far as I know.  Perhaps a 3rd party keyboard?

Comment: Tom, that's marvellous, thanks. I'd certainly tick an answer on the lines of "Use the Italian keyboard, dummy" ;-). I never thought of that!